# TFS WorkItemStore access issues via code if impersonation is used

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm facing issues accessing a TFS WorkItemStore via C# code when I'm using impersonation. The code that I'm using is as follows:

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri("https://localtfsinstance/tfs);
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("tfsusername", "tfspassword", "ADDomain");
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(cred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);

TfsConfigurationServer _configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri, tfsCred);

ReadOnlyCollection <Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.CatalogNode> _collectionNodes = 
    _configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
    new[] {
    CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection
    }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.CatalogNode collectionNode = _collectionNodes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Resource.DisplayName == "MyProjCollection");

var tpcId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);

var tpc = _configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcId);

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore _wiStore = tpc.GetService<TF_WIT_Client.WorkItemStore>();
```

I have two domain accounts, both have equal permissions to TFS. If I use any of these accounts along with their respective password, the code works fine and the WorkItemStore is retrieved.

However, If I impersonate the application with the first domain account and use the second account for authentication with TFS, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=Collection node not found: ProjectCollectionName
>   'MyProjCollection'
>
> Inner Exception 1: COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been
>   returned from a call to a COM component.

Due to the way the application is written, skipping impersonation is not an option. Has anyone faced this issue before and/or knows a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order for impersonation to work, the user that the process is running as must have the “`Make requests on behalf of others`” permission for this collection.  If the user does not have this permission then you are going to see an Access Denied error message.

So, please give the user “`Make requests on behalf of others`” permission first.

You can reference below articles to use TFS Impersonation:

- [Using TFS Impersonation with the Version Control Client APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/03/29/using-tfs-impersonation-with-the-version-control-client-apis/)
- [TFS API Part 29 – TFS Impersonation](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/08/23/tfs-api-part-29-tfs-impersonation/)